# How to avoid problem with clean/smudge that prevents git from removing changes with `git restore <file>`?

Tags: bash, git, shell, zsh

Changes  mysteriously appeared in a file (`lib/spo_api.rb`) when I switched to `master`, and I could not get rid of the changes with `git restore` to switch back.  The shell history says it all more explicitly, but skip down to the bottom if you already understood.

```
  git status
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
    modified:   lib/spo_api.rb

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
  git diff
diff --git a/lib/spo_api.rb b/lib/spo_api.rb
index 4af1ffb..54628c4 100644
--- a/lib/spo_api.rb
+++ b/lib/spo_api.rb
@@ -22,4 +22,4 @@ class SpoApi
     { success: res.success?, data: data }
   end

-end
\ No newline at end of file
+end
  git restore lib/spo_api.rb
  git status
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
    modified:   lib/spo_api.rb

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

You can see that the first and last `git status` invocations are the same, and that `git restore lib/spo_api.rb` does nothing.

I tracked it down to something in my `.gitconfig`:

```
[filter "bindingpry"]
    clean = sed '/^\\s*-?binding.pry$/'d
    smudge = cat
```

This is here to prevent accidentally leaving `binding.pry` (for debugging in Ruby) in a codebase, and it works perfectly as long as all files have a final newline, as they *should*.  Of course I can't control the behavior of every developer who goes before me, or who works in the same repo concurrently with me, and while of course I have plans to clean up such files in repos I work in, it would also be nice if I didn't get shot in the foot by my own safety measures.

What would make the above filter work as I want it to?   (I'm using zsh but I imagine 98% of what works in Bash will work for me too.)

Comment: It looks like a problem of line endings. Open the files before and after switching branches with an editor that can show the line endings, to see what exactly the endings are. They might be `CRLF`, `CR` and `LF`.

Comment: Some versions of sed may be able handle a file that doesn't end in newline, but most will mess with it (e.g., will add a newline). There isn't a proper way to handle this directly in Git: you'd need a variant of sed that handles this, or to use a filter other than sed. I suspect if you run `git rm lib/spo_api.rb; git restore lib/spo_api.rb` that you'll go back to the no-newline-at-end-of-file state and Git will be happy, for this particular case, though.

Comment: Assuming that works, you've hit a corner case: Git cleaned the file (adding the newline) and then assumed that the result was right and now doesn't actually bother re-smudging as it thinks the work-tree copy matches the index copy. But it doesn't actually match, because of the added newline. Removing and restoring will force a one-way trip that gets you back the lack-of-newline edition.